# Rename "view close votes" to reflect what it actually means

Tags: feature-request, privileges, help-center, privileges-page

The privilege "view close votes" is very confusingly named. It's not actually about *viewing* much of anything, since any votes you can view are only as a side effect of being able to *cast* votes, and it only applies to *your own* questions, which is not in the name at all. What's more, arguably the most important aspect of it is the ability to cast *reopen* votes on your own questions, which is also not in the name.

Instead, let's call it something like "[cast] self-close and self-reopen votes". This is sufficiently evocative that someone who knows vaguely what that refers to will remember it. And it's sufficiently unambiguous that anyone who doesn't know what it refers to will know they have no idea what it means and need to go look it up — in contrast to the current one, which seems clear but is actually quite misleading. Finally, this is also not much longer than the current privilege names, so it should probably fit into the table with just a bit of squeezing.